# Handwritten Signature Verification

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am working on a Signature Verification project . I have used the [ICDAR 2011 Signature Dataset](http://www.iapr-tc11.org/mediawiki/index.php/ICDAR_2011_Signature_Verification_Competition_(SigComp2011)).Currently,I am pairing the encoding of an original image and a forgery to get a training sample(labelled 0). The encodings are obtained from a pre-trained VGG-16 convolutional neural network (removing the fully connected layer). I have then modified the fully connected layer having the following architecture :

- Input size : 50177
- 1st hidden layer : 1000 units (activation : "sigmoid",Dropout : 0.5)
- 2nd hidden layer : 500 units (activation : "sigmoid",Dropout : 0.2)
- Output Layer : 1 unit (activation : "sigmoid")

The issue is that although the training set accuracy increases the validation accuracy fluctuates randomly.It performs very badly on the test set

I have tried different architectures but nothing seems to work
So is there any other way to prepare the data or should I continue trying different architectures??

Comment: what's the training, validation, test ratio? Have you tried Inception as well?

Comment: Train : 95%, Validation : 2.5% ,Test : 2.5% .For further testing Signs of one user was not included in the entire dataset. Inception is not computationally possible,tried it.

Comment: Your train/test/validation behavior indicates you're likely overfitting - the model is basically doing rote memorization. It's not guessing randomly on all sets, so it can learn *something* about the features, the model is just bad at discriminating between them right now. Might be worthwhile to try to use more, smaller layers.

Comment: Try 75:15:10 or 80:10:10

Comment: @user8407600 Overfitting is a difference between train and validation accuracy but in here validation set has greater accuracy than the training set.Tried some smaller architectures too ,leads to underfitting.I think I should use a different network for generating the embeddings

Comment: You've said before it fluctuates randomly, not that it's consistently higher. That seems like a bit of contradiction. Is it consistently better or not?

Comment: For some architectures,it is consistently better but for some validation accuracy fluctuates

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that using a VGG16 model for features extraction for your task is the right way to go. You are using a model that was trained on relatively complex RGB images and than try to use it for a dataset that basically consists of grayscale images of edges (signatures). And you are using the last embedding layer which contains the most complex and specialized representation of the ImageNet dataset (the original training dataset for the VGG model).

The features you get have no real meaning and that is probably why the training accuracy and validation accuracy are not correlated at all when you try to fine-tune the model.

My suggestion is to either use an earlier layer of the VGG16 for feature extraction (I'm talking somewhere around layer no.5-6), or better yet, **use a simpler model that was trained on a more similar dataset**, like the MNIST dataset.

The **MNIST** dataset consists of handwritten digits so it is considerably more similar to your task and any model trained on it will act as a much better feature extractor for your task.
You can pick any model from the following list of benchmark results on the MNIST and use it as a feature extractor:

[MNIST Benchmark Results](http://rodrigob.github.io/are_we_there_yet/build/classification_datasets_results.html#4d4e495354)